# Can you add custom validation to Laravel Nova Action using external variable?

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-nova

I'm using a Nova action to change a date. To validate the date change, I need to make sure the new date is after the old date. For some reason I'm having a really hard time accessing the old date (which is not a field, just a value attached to the user model). This is what I have:

```js
public function fields()
{
    // Get old date. This works when the action loads.
    $oldShipDate = Carbon::parse($this->user->ship_date)

    return [
        Date::make('New Ship Date', 'new_ship_date')
          // Using withMeta so that calendar pops up with old ship date selected - this works
            ->withMeta(['value' => $oldShipDate])
            ->rules('required','after:' . $oldShipDate),
        }),

        // Other fields

    ];
}
```

I see in Nova 4.0 they've added a `min()` option that would fix all of this, but I'm on Nova 3.0. I've also tried a custom validation function and a custom rule, but I still can't access $this->user when the form is submitted. Is it possible to access `ship_date` on validation somehow? Last resort is to check the new date against the old date in the action logic, but that feels hacky.

Answer (score 0):

About this type of validation or accessing data from action must you first use  single line action only not bulk see below example is work correctly, also it's fix the null

Action File must be like this

```
class ChangeShipDate extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    public function __construct(
        private Order $order,
    )
    {}
    
    
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models):?array
    {
        if(isset($fields->ship_date)){
            $order = $models->first();
            $order->ship_date = $fields->ship_date;
            $order->save();
            return Action::message(__('Ship Date Changed'));
        }
        return null;
    }


    public function fields(NovaRequest $request): array
    {
        if(isset($this->order->ship_date)){
                $oldShipDate = Carbon::parse($this->order?->ship_date);

                return [
                    Date::make('New Ship Date', 'new_ship_date')
                        ->withMeta(['value' => $oldShipDate])
                        ->rules('required','after:' . $oldShipDate),
                    // Other fields
                ];
        }
        return [];
    }


}
```

In Order Resource must call like this

```
public function actions(NovaRequest $request): array
{
    return [
        (new ChangeShipDate($this->getModel()))
            ->onlyOnDetail()
            ->onlyOnIndex(),

    ];
}
```

> Note: If you run as multiple row it will not work just must be onDetail and Index to work with singleton action